# Problems with Xalan and Java JDK 1.5

Tags: java, java-5, xalan, xslt

From what I believe and have read online. Sun has decided to include Xalan in JDK 1.5. I am trying to take advantage of this and try to perform an XSLT to spit out multiple files. The problem I encounter:

`'Unrecognized XSLTC extension 'org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect:write''"`

From what I have read on google that i needed to change:

```
xmlns:redirect="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect"
```

to

```
xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
```

in XSL transforms

When I apply this change to my .XSL File, I appear to be getting the same error. Need to get this working ASAP and can't seem to find an answer online. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not really a great idea to make use of implementation-specific features. (Apart from which, 1.5 has finished its EOSL period, 1.6 has been out since 2006.)

Comment: Hmm, well this isnt personal its work related. They are still at 1.5. Well, another problem I have is setting everything up. I found online instructions quite vague regarding setting up Xalan.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignored the JDK's default Xalan. I just added the files from Xalan. Better, that way I can just use that rather than depending on a single JDK.